# Static object has separate instance in BroadCastReceiver execution?

Tags: android

I have a static, singleton instance of a SQLiteOpenHelper implementation.

```
public class MyDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myapp.db";

    public static SQL_CREATE_MY_TABLE ="some correct table creation sql";      
    public static SQL_DELETE_MY_TABLE="some correct table delete sql";
    ...


    public MyDbHelper (Context context) {
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_MY_TABLE);
      db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_OTHER_TABLE);       
    }

  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

      db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_MY_TABLE);
      db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_OTHER_TABLE);          
      onCreate(db);

   }
}
```

I have another wrapper over the helper as:

```
 public class MyAppDb {

    private static MyDbHelper mydbHelper;

    public static MyDbHelper getDbHelper(){
        if(null == mydbHelper){
            mydbHelper= new MyDbHelper(ctx);
            return mydbHelper;
        }else{
            return mydbHelper;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the mydbHelper from this getDbHelper() in my main Ui code(at various places), as well as in a BroadcastReceiver of an Alarmmanager that executes every 5 mins, and in another system BroadcastReceiver.

Sample usage:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = MyAppDb.getDbHelper().getReadableDatabase();
```

Intermittently, I get SQLiteDatabaseLockedException and SQLiteException on the the db implementations from the above mydbHelper.
It seems as though although static, there are two different instances of the MyDbHelper occuring at the same time.

What is happening? Can a static object have a separate instance created from BroadCastReceiver?

Or I am doing it wrong?

Comment: That code is not thread-safe. Mark the field as `volatile` and add `synchronized` to `getDbHelper()`. Also, if your `BroadcastReceiver` (or the service that it delegates to) is in a separate process, each process has its own objects.

Comment: The snippet you posted seems to be doing a lot of things wrong, or maybe I'm missing some key details. Your functions seem to be declared outside of the class and I think a peek at the implementation will make your problem easier to solve.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "if your BroadcastReceiver (or the service that it delegates to) is in a separate process" ? Aren't BroadcastReceivers always a separate process spawned by the Android's system?

Comment: Added implementation code.. actual code is the same,albeit with more tables.